# Can I stop MediaElementsJS from triggering an IE Silverlight update warning?

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement.js

I am using MediaElementJS on my site and some IE9 users are seeing a warning from the browser which says "Silverlight was blocked because it is out of date and needs to be updated".

I really don't want any users to see this message, but even if I remove silverlight from the plugins list when I initialise MediaElementJS so that it won't try to use it, the users still see the warning.

Is there something I can do to force MediaElementJS to not try to use Silverlight at all so that the warning does not appear?
Or any other solution to suppress this warning?

Thanks, P

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this? I have not found a solution yet. Thanks,